# How to manage 3rdparty library in git repo

Tags: c, git, libraries

I am looking for suggestions on how to manage C' 3rd party libraries in my git repos.

I'm maintaining two git repositories:

1. **repo A** - my main repository, which contains my program source code
2. **repo B** - secondary repository which contains many private libraries source code.

Repo A is dependent on **some** libraries from repo B and those libraries required for successful compilation.

What is the right way of getting the required libraries from repo B?

Few approaches I thought of:

1. Git submodule gives me everything I need. The only cons here is that repo B is very large, and I need only a few modules within that repository. There is a way to define only parts of repo B as a submodule?
2. Git hooks - Creating git hooks which download compiled version of the libraries (.so) save them in libs/ folder. The link to the libraries will be supplied in a file. In every branch checkout, the hook needs to check if a different version of the libraries should be downloaded.
   (Never worked with git hooks, I'm not sure if it is possible)

Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you talking about? I guess C?

Comment: Yea, C language